# Session values not getting cleared

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

For example : 
We are going a multiple registration,the user enters their details and verifies them.
while doing second registration the session values (Values of the first registration) doesn't get cleared in Internet Explorer were else its getting cleared in chrome or firefox

Could anybody help in clearing it?

Comment: can you post some of your code? or post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Maybe autofill settings, or some plugin (LastPass)?